# hibernate exception with UNION

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have this Query with using JPA / Hibernate. I have just added the second SELECT with the UNION clause. Before that, the query worked well :

```
Query q = entityMgr.createQuery("SELECT n FROM FoaNotification n left join fetch n.foaLecteurs "
            + " where n.foaParamTypeNotif.idTypNotif = :pIdTypeNotif and n.codAgence = :pCodeAgence and n.icArchive = 'N' and n.origine != :pOrigine and n.foaParamStatutNotif.idStatutNotif = 1 and (n.idAgent IS NULL OR n.idAgent = :pIdUserGrc) and n.icImportEnCours='N' "
            + "UNION "
            + "SELECT o FROM Notification o left join fetch o.Lecteurs "
            + "where o.foaParamTypeNotif.idTypNotif = :pIdTypeNotifAffTache and o.codAgence = :pCodeAgence and o.icArchive = 'N' and o.origine != :pOrigine and o.foaParamStatutNotif.idStatutNotif = 1 and (o.idAgent != :pIdUserGrc) and n.icImportEnCours='N' "
            + "ORDER BY n.dateCreation DESC")
            .setParameter("pIdTypeNotif", pIdTypeNotif)
            .setParameter("pCodeAgence", pCodeAgence)
            .setParameter("pIdUserGrc", pIdUserGrc)
            .setParameter("pOrigine", Constants.EVENT_ORIGINE_IMPORT_CLIENT)
            .setParameter("pIdTypeNotifAffTache", Constants.TYPE_NOTIFICATION_AFFECTATION_TACHE);
```

`Constants.EVENT_ORIGINE_IMPORT_CLIENT`and `Constants.TYPE_NOTIFICATION_AFFECTATION_TACHE`are defined like this :

```
public static final long TYPE_NOTIFICATION_AFFECTATION_TACHE = 4;
public static final String EVENT_ORIGINE_IMPORT_CLIENT = "IMPORT_CL";
```

This is right regards to entities definition :

```
public class FoaParamTypeNotif implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="ID_TYP_NOTIF", unique=true, nullable=false, precision=2)
    private long idTypNotif;

    @Column(name="LIB_TYP_NOTIF", nullable=false, length=200)
    private String libTypNotif;
}
```

Got this exception, doesn't understand why :

```
GRAVE: EJB Exception: : java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ParameterTranslationsImpl.getNamedParameterExpectedType(ParameterTranslationsImpl.java:87)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.buildParameterMetadata(HQLQueryPlan.java:318)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:121)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:119)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:215)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:193)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1649)
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:286)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor311.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.AbstractBeanInstance.invoke(AbstractBeanInstance.java:44)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:105)
....
....
```

I checked spaces and things like that but it seems that it's right written.

Comment: since its thrown from "getNamedParameterExpectedType" perhaps has something to do with the TYPE of the PARAMETERS. We cant see what they are (and should be) since you post insufficient info

Comment: what is n.foaParamTypeNotif.idTypNotif and o.foaParamTypeNotif.idTypNotif?

Comment: UNION is not supported by HQL/JPQL. If you absolutely need it, use SQL.